# localhost is redirecting to http://www.yoursite.com/307.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver, localhost

This is a unexpected error, what should i do my localhost is redirceting to
           http://www.yoursite.com/307.php

When i try to open localhost or 127.0.0.1 pr my LAN address 192.168.1.103 i am being redireted to

http://www.yoursite.com/307.php

i also tried 127.0.0.1 and also my LAN  address

i have checked etc/hosts..., nothinng is there?

Please help somebody

Comment: What wamp package are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Browse to Start -> All Programs -> Accessories

2) Right click "Notepad" and select "Run as administrator"

3) Click "Continue" on the UAC prompt

4) Click File -> Open

5) Browse to "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc"

6) Change the file filter drop down box from "Text Documents (*.txt)" to "All Files (*.*)"

7) Select "hosts" and click "Open"

8) Make the needed changes and close Notepad. Save when prompted.

Comment: I just want to open localhost.., was working fine for months...,

Comment: In which format did you put it..ideally IP and HostName should be separated by atleast one space.. 
127.0.0.1      localhost